# Can't remove or disable old users in Dynamics CRM Online 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

How do I delete and create a new instance on Dynamics CRM Online 2016 with a clean set of Users?

Our organisation has Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online internal use rights (IUR) benefit for MPN members with 15 licences. This gives us a Production and a Sandbox licence to use.

I have assigned 10 license.

When I delete and recreate either the Sandbox or Production instance I get my 10 users I expect, but then I also have 4 additional users which I think came from an earlier on premise version of CRM we were trialing.

The Full name either has a # symbol at the beginning or the end of their name.
These other 4 users do not consume a licence but are listed under the enabled users. I can't disable them or seem to get rid of them.

How can I completely reset my Dynamics CRM Online 2016 instances?

Deleting them and recreating them just seems to always create the same set of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the users being assigned the role of "Global Administrator" in Office 365.

Any users marked with the role of "Global Administrator" will be automatically included in your Dynamics CRM Online users. Even if they are not assigned a Dynamics CRM Online licence.

The good news is that they do not consume a CRM licence. The bad new is that they are always active in the list.